# Venda de selos automatizada (Python)

Tags: python

Boa tarde, sera conseguiriam me ajudar com um problema de python?

Eu preciso:

(1) Calcule a quantidade de selos de 50 e 20 centavos a serem compradas pelo usuário.

(2) Dica 2: Para descobrir como calcular a quantidade de selos, pense sempre em pegar a maior quantidade possível de selos de 50 (análogo ao problema da tinta, mas agora não é permitido comprar selos a mais, o valor deve ser exato). Portanto faça uma tabela com os preços de 10 em 10 centavos, escreva para cada caso quantos selos são necessários e tente encontrar um padrão. 
Por exemplo, a maior quantidade de selos de 50 para um custo de R$ 1,10 é 2, mas ai não conseguimos preencher os 10 centavos que faltam. Mas é possível chegar ao valor exato com um selo de 50 a menos e 3 selos de 20. Seguindo este exemplo, o que acontece com o valor de 1,60? e 2,10? 2,60? Qual a relação entre esses valores e o selo de 50?

O que eu fiz até agora:

```
custo = round(100*float(input()))
while custo<70 or custo>620 or custo%10!=0:
    print('Preco invalido, refa?a a leitura do pacote.')
    custo = round(100*float(input()))
    selos_50 = custo//50
    selos = custo-(selos_50*50)/20
    if selos==0:
        selos_20 = custo//20
        selos = (custo-selos_50*20)/50
    else:
    print('Compre',selos_20,'selo(s) de R$ 0.50 e',selos_50,'selo(s) de R$ 0.20!')
```

O while feito foi para validação das entradas. Ai eu preciso nesse print mostrar quantos seles de 20 e 50 tenho que usar.

Sera que tem como dar um help?

Answer (score 0):

primeiro divida o valor por 0.5

```
selo_50 = custo / 0.5
resto_50 = custo % 0.5
```

Blz, mas agora pode ser que o troco não possa ser divido por 0.2.
exemplo 1.10 divido 0.5 = 2, sobra 0.1

Neste caso diminua um selo de 50 e vai sobrar mais 0.5
no exemplo 0.1 + 0.5 = 0.6 que é divisivel por 0.2

```
if ( resto_50 % 0.2 != 0 ):
  selo_50 -= 1
  resto_50 += 0.5

selo_20 = resto_50 / 0.2
```